# random variables i.i.d and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the sum of random variables $L_k = \sum_j K_j$,  $K_k \in \mathbb{N_0}$ are i.i.d.
Now I want to calculate:

$$E(L_p| L_{p+j}=j) $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line should be
$$E(S_m \mid S_{m+n} = n) = \sum_{j=0}^n j P(S_m = j \mid S_{m+n} = n).$$

Then note that
$$P(S_m = j \mid S_{m+n} = n) = \frac{P(S_m = j, S_{m+n} = n)}{P(S_{m+n}=n)}$$
where the numerator is $$P(S_m = j, S_{m+n} = n) = P(S_m = j, S_{m+n} - S_m = n-j) = P(S_m = j) P(S_n = n-j)$$
because $S_{m+n} - S_m$ is independent of $S_m$ and has the same distribution as $S_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I did edit my mistake. How you rewrite the numerator was the important step for me:)